# Java DB Derby and Netbeans 7.1 Build Problems

Tags: java, database, netbeans, jar, derby

My application accesses a Derby Database and I have added the Derby.jar to the libraries in the project. It runs fine when compiled and runs perfectly inside the Netbeans environment but once I Build the project, only my application.jar file is in the dist folder. The program will still run but once I try doing anything with the database it hangs.

I tried adding the lib folder containing Derby.jar to the home directory of the application.jar but I still get the same problem.

I'm new to Derby and I'm confused by this, any suggestions?

Comment: Where do you deploy your application or is it just a desktop app?

Comment: BTW - did you check, that the jar is deploed with the application? In netbeans you have to check the box where u add the jars to your project.

Comment: I have the 'Copy Dependent Libraries' box checked if that's what you mean? And yes it is a desktop app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you don't also add the project external jar dependencies (such as Derby's jar) to the classpath of your project's executable jar.  Basicly, try following their tutorial here:

http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html#Exercise_1

the chapter entitled "Running the Application Outside of the IDE" and the one after that.

I haven't used Netbeans in a long while so I don't know if they added this functionality to it now, but with Eclipse you can also make a "fat" executable jar, where all the external jars are packed inside that executable jar, and Eclipse adds a special classloader which makes all this work. It's the option called "Package required libraries into generated jar". Maybe Netbeans lets you do that now too, via some export function or something similar.

Comment: I have read the tutorial and that is more or less what I have already done though my manifest file only contains:           Manifest-Version: 1.0
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Do you reckon I should add something like:                             Class-Path: lib/Derby.jar  to the manifest?

Answer (score 1):

The answer 1 above does not address the fact the you need to first connect to the database in the service tab of the IDE before you can run your application and that  is not possible when you run your application outside the IDE.